# How can a red dwarf have such an immense lifetime?

Tags: astrophysics, stellar-physics, stellar-evolution

I understand what a red dwarf is, and that it is dominated by convection. But I still don't understand how the fusion processes in such a tiny star can keep going for the immense time predicted.

Among the points that perplex me are - (a) the incredibly slow fusion rate (comparatively) this suggests; (b) convection usually implies mixing which can cool, but obviously doesn't cool enough to stop fusion, and implies mixing which suggests fuel is uniformly available; (c) the very slow speed combined with failure to cease fusion suggests some kind of self regulatory process, but one that keeps it "almost on the brink", (d) it applies to all red dwarfs but these have a range of masses so why don't some speed up and why are the lifetimes *all* extremely long?

What is going on, to create/allow this?

Comment: "convection usually implies mixing which can cool" That's not entirely true.  You could say _every_ type of heat transfer implies cooling, the same way to also implies heating.  This is because it really is the _transfer_ of heat from one place to another.  If something is losing heat, something else is gaining it.

Comment: Perhaps [this article on space.com](https://www.space.com/23772-red-dwarf-stars.html) might help.  Also suggest migrations to [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic physics behind the long lifetimes of stars is that the nuclear fusion process that takes place during the majority of their lives is very slow.

In low mass stars, such as the ones mentioned in your question, and in the Sun, the dominant process is the pp chain, that combines protons and ultimately turns them into Helium nuclei. The rate-determining step is the fusion of two protons and the subsequent  beta-plus decay of one of the protons to  produce a stable deuterium nucleus. This is slow because the protons have to overcome the Coulomb repulsion between them, and can only do so (at the temperatures and densities inside a star) by improbable quantum tunneling, and the subsequent beta-plus decay is governed by the weak nuclear force. It is calculated that even in the centre of the Sun, the fusion reactions only yield about 0.25 kW per cubic metre - less than a compost heap.

The key to the stability of stars is the strong temperature dependence of the fusion reactions and hydrostatic equilibrium. If the rate of nuclear reactions were to fall in the centre, then because (in the low-mass stars you discuss) convection efficiently transports energy outwards, the core would cool and the pressure would fall. As a result the star would contract, the central pressure and temperature rise and the fusion reaction rate would increase again. Conversely, if the reactions speed up, the core temperature and pressure would initially rise, but the star would expand until a new equilibrium was found at a lower reaction rate. This negative feedback on the nuclear reaction rate is what gives the star it's stability.

Contrary to what you say, the lifetime of a star in this phase is very mass dependent. Roughly, the lifetime is equal to ten billion years, multiplied by $(M/M_{\odot})^{-2.5}$, where mass is expressed in solar units. So even though they have more fuel, higher mass stars have shorter lifetimes. The reason is that high mass stars require higher temperatures and pressures to support their weight and this leads to much  higher fusion reaction rates and shorter lifetimes to burn through the available fuel.

Comment: That 0.25kW/m^3 number is going into my list of really fascinating figures.

Comment: Fun fact: hamsters on wheels in small cages would be sufficient to power the sun (for the very short time before they gravitationally collapsed, of course).

Answer (score 2):

There are two factors that come into play.

- **The low fusion rate.**

  This should be obvious. If you burn a pile of fuel slowly you can keep it burning longer. And these stars burn excruciatingly slowly.
- **Convection means the whole star is fuel**

  In medium mass stars most of the mass is not accessible for use as fuel because the inner portion of the star is still and matter migrates by diffusion only. Such star develop helium enriched cores forcing fusion into a layer around the core as Virial collapse warms the interior enough for that to happen.

  When the whole star is convective all the mass make its way to the core from time to time, and so becomes a candidate for burning.